# Missing ASP.NET MVC Template in Microsoft Blend

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Microsoft Blend (blend.exe) to work on a pet project from home. My project is going to use ASP.NET MVC but the template to start up is not available. I have looked at many other posts that have fixes for Visual Studio (devenv.exe) but none of them work for Blend. How can I get all the basic templates installed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to not use Blend at all. None of the basic templates are available. The templates you will find are full app examples. Use Visual Studio Community edition and you will find all the templates you need to get your projects started.